# execute python script in vim [windows]

Tags: python, vim, windows-7

I'm trying to run python scripts in vim. I got the code below to put in my python.vim in the plugin folder:

```
map <buffer> <S-e> :w<CR>:!/usr/bin/env python % <CR>
```

but it appears to be Linux. Is there any way to tweak it and get around with Win7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How bout `map :w:!C:/path/to/your/python %`?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the python.exe path immediately after the `!`. For example:

```
map :w:!C:\Python27\python.exe %
```

Comment: weird thing is I changed the code to map :w:!C:\Python27\python.exe % it still show the error mgs: usr/bin/env python the system cannot find the path specified. Do I need to change anything else? Thx!!

Comment: Do you have `#!/usr/bin/env python` declared at the top of the script you're executing? Cause you shouldn't.

Comment: No it's just the original python.vim file in the ftplugin folder. And I just added this single line. Not sure what's wrong...

Comment: I figured it out: simply map to "!python %".

Answer (score 0):

Try `map <buffer> <S-e> :w<CR>:!C:\Python27\python.exe % <CR>`